# PhpStorm, recent projects only show folder names instead of project name

Tags: phpstorm

Some time ago PhpStorm started to only show the **foldernames** of my projects instead of the **project name**. This is very annoying since all my projects follow the same folder structure:

> C:\webserver\ [Client] \ [Project] \ htdocs

See this screenshot:

[image: PhpStorm Recent Projects Panel]

I tried:

- Renaming the Project inside PhpStorm
- Editing the **.iml** and **.name** Files inside the  **.idea** folder

Both did not solve my problem.

I am using PhpStorm 2016.2 EAP. Project name does show up correctly in the title bar of PhpStorm itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a regression in 2016.2 version that quite few people have faced.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156993 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

**UPDATE:** (21-July-2016)
This issue is resolved in 2016.2.1 (EAP build 162.1447.5 from 20/07/2016).

---

Is there any reason why you cannot create a project 1 folder up (which would usually be named after actual project name/domain name)? This would solve your problem (at least in your case).

Comment: Not really. Its just I have alot of projects. Hoped there would be an easy fix. 
Anyway, I starred the youtrack issue. Thank you

Comment: This bug is fixed now in EAP Build:

PhpStorm 2016.2.1
Build #PS-162.1447.5, built on July 19, 2016